# The necessary and sufficient condition for exchanging the integration process and the limit process

Tags: integration, limits

We only consider real functions here. It can be shown that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}} & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}

It is obvious that the integration $\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\sqrt{x}\cos x$
is not convergent. But here I will show another way to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\sqrt{x}\cos x$.
We can see
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\sqrt{x}\cos(kx) & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\sin(kx)=\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\lim_{\Delta k\to0}\frac{\sin[(k+\Delta k)x]-\sin(kx)}{\Delta k}
\end{eqnarray*}

Suppose that the integration process and the limit process can be
exchanged, then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\sqrt{x}\cos(kx) & = & \lim_{\Delta k\to0}\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\sin[(k+\Delta k)x]-\sin(kx)}{\Delta k}\\
 & = & \lim_{\Delta k\to0}\frac{1}{\Delta k}\bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{\sin[(k+\Delta k)x]}{\sqrt{x}}-\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{\sin(kx)}{\sqrt{x}}\bigg)\\
 & = & \lim_{\Delta k\to0}\frac{1}{\Delta k}\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+\Delta k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\bigg)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\
 & = & \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d}{dk}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\\
 & = & -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}
\end{eqnarray*}

i.e.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\sqrt{x}\cos(kx) & = & -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}
\end{eqnarray*}

then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\sqrt{x}\cos x & = & \bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\sqrt{x}\cos(kx)\bigg)_{k=1}=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}

which conflicts with the non-convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\sqrt{x}\cos x$.
This confliction may be due to the fact that the integration process
and the limit process can not be exchanged. So my question (which
may be naive to mathematicians) is: what is the necessary and sufficient
condition for exchanging the integration process and the limit process?

Comment: I'm not aware of a **necessary** and sufficient condition for exchanging the limit and the integral. But there is many theorems that gives sufficient conditions

Comment: Please: write \cos x, not \mathrm{cos}x.  Don't you see the conspicuous lack of proper spacing with the latter? Contrast 2\cos x with 2\mathrm{cos}x: $$ 2\cos x \quad\text{versus}\quad2\mathrm{cos}x $$ The spacing is different in 2\cos(x): $$2\cos(x)$$ \mathrm{} doesn't have any context-depended spacing conventions built in to it. I edited the question. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy...Thanks for your suggestions! I have replaced \mathrm{cos}x by \cos x everywhere.

Comment: @Tryss...Can you recommend some mathematical book that involves sufficient condition for exchanging the limit and the integral? Thank you very much.

Comment: Any book on real analysis? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem for just one such theorem.